# form is getting submitted even after returing false

Tags: javascript, php, validation

**my script**

```
   <script>
    function hii(Name,Mobile){
        let Count=0;
        if(Name=="" || Name==null){
            document.getElementById('nameerror').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('nameerror').innerHTML='Please Enter Student Name';
            Count++;
        }
        if(Mobile=="" || Mobile==null){
            document.getElementById('mobileerror').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('mobileerror').innerHTML='Please Enter Student Mobile';
            Count++;
        }
        if(Count>0){
            alert(Count);
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Html**

```
<form action="addstudent.php" method="POST" onsubmit="hii(
    document.getElementById('name').value,
    document.getElementById('mobile').value
)">

    <input type="text" name='name' id="name" placeholder="Enter Student Name"><br><br>
        <label for="" id="nameerror" style="display: none;color:red;font-size:small;"></label>
    <input type="number" name='mobile' id='mobile' placeholder="Enter Mobile Number"><br><br>
        <label for="" id="mobileerror" style="display: none;color:red;font-size:small;"></label>
    
    <input type="submit" value="add">
</form>
```

> im getting count as 2 via alert after submitting form with no data which means there are no errors in my html and javascript code and i cant find any flashing errors in console

Comment: Use onsubmit="return hii(...)"

Comment: Please see my answer. I would prefer to use ```addEventListener```.

Comment: thankyou bro got it..

Comment: use onsubmit="return hii()" instead of onsubmit="hii()" simple way

Comment: @HariBattula, what if you add more input field in your form? The simple way is ```addEventListener()```. This way you don't need to change the hii function in the html

Answer (score 3):

What you need is to pass an `event` to the submit function, and use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the submission.

```js
function hii(event, Name, Mobile) {
  let Count = 0;
  if (Name == "" || Name == null) {
    document.getElementById("nameerror").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("nameerror").innerHTML =
      "Please Enter Student Name";
    Count++;
  }
  if (Mobile == "" || Mobile == null) {
    document.getElementById("mobileerror").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("mobileerror").innerHTML =
      "Please Enter Student Mobile";
    Count++;
  }
  if (Count > 0) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(Count);
  }
}
```

```html
<form
  action="addstudent.php"
  method="POST"
  onsubmit="hii(
    event,
    document.getElementById('name').value,
    document.getElementById('mobile').value
)"
>
  <input
    type="text"
    name="name"
    id="name"
    placeholder="Enter Student Name"
  /><br /><br />
  <label
    for=""
    id="nameerror"
    style="display: none; color: red; font-size: small"
  ></label>
  <input
    type="number"
    name="mobile"
    id="mobile"
    placeholder="Enter Mobile Number"
  /><br /><br />
  <label
    for=""
    id="mobileerror"
    style="display: none; color: red; font-size: small"
  ></label>

  <input type="submit" value="add" />
</form>
```

A better solution is to use `addEventListener()`

```js
document.querySelector("#form1").addEventListener("submit", hii);

function hii(event) {
  const Name = document.querySelector("#name").value;
  const Mobile = document.querySelector("#mobile").value;
  
  let Count = 0;
  if (Name == "" || Name == null) {
    document.getElementById("nameerror").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("nameerror").innerHTML =
      "Please Enter Student Name";
    Count++;
  }
  if (Mobile == "" || Mobile == null) {
    document.getElementById("mobileerror").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("mobileerror").innerHTML =
      "Please Enter Student Mobile";
    Count++;
  }
  if (Count > 0) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(Count);
  }
}
```

```html
<form
  id="form1"
  action="addstudent.php"
  method="POST"
>
  <input
    type="text"
    name="name"
    id="name"
    placeholder="Enter Student Name"
  /><br /><br />
  <label
    for=""
    id="nameerror"
    style="display: none; color: red; font-size: small"
  ></label>
  <input
    type="number"
    name="mobile"
    id="mobile"
    placeholder="Enter Mobile Number"
  /><br /><br />
  <label
    for=""
    id="mobileerror"
    style="display: none; color: red; font-size: small"
  ></label>

  <input type="submit" value="add" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the value in the handler

```
<form action="addstudent.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return hii(
    document.getElementById('name').value,
    document.getElementById('mobile').value
)">
```

But better yet is to keep it all together in your script

```
<form action="addstudent.php" method="POST">
   <!-- remove the onsubmit here --> 
<input type="submit" value="add">
   <!-- we'll put the listener here -->
```

Then, your script

```
document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let Count = 0;
    let Name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    let Mobile = document.getElementById('mobile').value
  if (Name == "" || Name == null) {
    document.getElementById('nameerror').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('nameerror').innerHTML = 'Please Enter Student Name';
    Count++;
  }
  if (Mobile == "" || Mobile == null) {
    document.getElementById('mobileerror').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('mobileerror').innerHTML = 'Please Enter Student Mobile';
    Count++;
  }
  if (Count > 0) {
    alert(Count);
    return false;
  }
  document.querySelector('form').submit()
})
```